# How to manipulate value of one Model Field from another Model?

Tags: python, django

I have two models

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ID = models.IntegerField()
    basic_salary = models.IntegerField()     
    total_leave = models.IntegerField(default = 14)
    paid_leave = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    unpaid_leave = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Leave_management(models.Model):

    name = models.OnetoOneField(Employee,on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    reason = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    from = models.DateTimeField()
    to = models.DateTimeField()
    total_days = models.IntegerField()

     def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

So,i want to minus 'total_days' of 'model-Leave_management'  from 'total_leave' field of 'model-Employee'. And as per leaves taken i want to update 'paid_leave' and 'unpaid_leave' sections.

I can perform so if these two models would be one model(example below), But i dont know how to perform so in different models.

```
def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
    if self.total_days<=self.total_leave:
        self.total_leave -= self.total_days
        self.unpaid_leave = 14 - self.total_leave
   else:
       self.total_days -= 14
       self.paid_leaves = self.total_days
   super(Model_name,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

`
 Please be guiding me.

Comment: Hold on, the `OneToOneField` is **not** a `name`. In the database it is the same type as the primary key, and in Django it is a *lazy* fetch.

Comment: Furthermore it is also very strange to define this on the `.save(..)` function. This means that each time you save the function, it will subtract another number of days?

Comment: Looks to me you want `total_leave` to be 14 minus the sum of `toal_days` of `Leave_management` that corresponds to that `Employee`. Correct?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem well its just for practice purpose, btw never thought  that way! well ,yes it would be a problem !

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes , total_leave(Employee Model) = total_leave(Employee Model)   *minus* total_days(Leave_Management Model)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact your `OneToOneField(..)` to an `Employee` is *not* a `name`. At the database level it will store values that correspond to *primary keys* of an `Employee`, and in Django, `name` will be a *lazy* fetch to the corresponding `Employee`. Therefore I suggest to rename your function to (for example) `employee`.

Another problem is that you define it as a `OneToOneField`. That means that an `Employee` has *one* `Leave_management`. But based on the fields (`reason`, `from`, `to`, etc.), it looks like an `Employee` can have zero, one, or more `Leave_management`s. So that means it is a `ForeignKey`.

So our model looks like:

```
class Leave_management(models.Model):

    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee,on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    reason = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    from = models.DateTimeField()
    to = models.DateTimeField()
    total_days = models.IntegerField()

     def __str__(self):
        return self.employee.name
```

Like the `__str__` function already suggests, we can obtain the name of the employee by querying `self.employee`, and we can then fetch its `.name` attribute.

But now the challenge is what to do when save a `Leave_management` object. In that case the number of `total_leave` and `paid_leave` should be updated.

We first have to figure out the total number of `total_days` that are stored in `Leave_management` objects related to an `Employee`, this is equal to:

```
(Leave_management.objects.filter(employee=some_employee)
                         .aggregate(totals=Sum('total_days'))['totals'] or 0
```

So we can then subtract this from `14`, and store the (possibly) remaining days in `paid_leave`, like:

```
class Leave_management(models.Model):

    # ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Leave_management, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        totals = (Leave_management.objects
                                  .filter(employee=some_employee)
                                  .aggregate(totals=Sum('total_days'))['totals'] or 0
        employee = self.employee
        unpaid = min(14, totals)
        employee.total_leave = 14 - unpaid
        employee.unpaid_leave = unpaid
        employee.paid_leave = totals - unpaid
        employee.save()
```

> **Note**: typically we do *not* handle this by overriding the `.save(..)` function, but by using Django *signals*: triggers that can be implemented when certain objects are saved, etc. This especially should be used since the objects can be changed circumventing the `.save(..)` function, and sometimes such objects might get deleted as well. So the above is **not a good design decision**.
>
> Even when we use signals, it is a good idea to frequently (for example once a day) recalculate the total leave, and update the corresponding `Employee` models.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, btw i tried to use signals ,then got integrity error with i could not able to debug.. .thats why went for neanderthal way..